# How to insert previous month of data into database Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have data in which i need to compare month of data if it is previous month then it should be insert otherwise not.

**Example:**

```
23.12.2016 12:02:23,Koji,24
22.01.2016 01:21:22,Mahi,24
```

Now i need to get first column of data (23.12.2016 12:02:23) and then get month (12) on it.

Compared that with before of current month like.,

```
If current month is 'JAN_2017',then get before of 'JAN_2017' it should be 'Dec_2016'
```

For First row,

**compare this 'Dec_2016'[month before] with month of data 'Dec_2016' [23.12.2016].**

It matched then insert into database.

**EDIT 1:**

i have already tried with your suggestions.

```
"UpdateAttribute to add a new attribute with the previous month value, and then RouteOnAttribute to determine if the flowfile should be inserted "
```

i have used below expression language in RouteOnAttribute,

```
${literal('Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'):getDelimitedField(${csv.1:toDate('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss'):format('MM')}):equals(${literal('Dec,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov'):getDelimitedField(${now():toDate(' Z MM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS yyyy'):format('MM'):toNumber()})})}
```

it could be failed in below data.,

```
23.12.2015,Andy,21
23.12.2017,Present,32
```

My data may contains some past years and future years

It matches with my expression it also inserted.

I need to check month with year in data.

How can i check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest answer is to use the `ExecuteScript` processor with simple date logic (this will allow you to use the Groovy/Java date framework to correctly handle things like leap years, time zones, etc.).

If you really don't want to do that, you could probably use a regex and Expression Language in `UpdateAttribute` to add a new attribute with the previous month value, and then `RouteOnAttribute` to determine if the flowfile should be inserted into the database.

Here's a simple Groovy test demonstrating the logic. You'll need to add the code to process the session, flowfile, etc.

```
@Test
public void textScriptShouldFindPreviousMonth() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    def input = ["23.12.2016 12:02:23,Koji,24", "22.01.2016 01:21:22,Mahi,24"]
    def EXPECTED = ["NOV_2016", "DEC_2015"]

    // Act
    input.eachWithIndex { String data, int i ->
        Calendar calendar = Date.parse("dd.MM.yyyy", data.tokenize(" ")[0]).toCalendar()
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)
        String result = calendar.format("MMM_yyyy").toUpperCase()

        // Assert
        assert result == EXPECTED[i]
    }
}
```