# Nifi - How to add or subtract months from date?

Tags: date, datetime, apache-nifi

I want to get two fields: `Begin date` and `End date` of last month. For example, `14-04-2020` should give me the `Begin date` as `01-03-2020` and `End_date` as `31-03-2020`. I have read the Nifi Expression language docs but all it can do with a date format is add or subtract in milliseconds. This is not helpful for my use case as the number of days in a month is not fixed and conversion to milliseconds won't help.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve my use case somehow using Nifi Expression language?

Comment: seems like you need to use ExecuteScript processor - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087834/how-to-obtain-first-date-of-each-month-based-on-given-year-range-in-nifi-flow

Comment: Yes you can, you just have to  put some effort in it "This is not helpful for my use case as the number of days in a month is not fixed and conversion to milliseconds won't help."

Answer (score 1):

@AdarshKumar

NiFI Expression Language for this Use Case would be very clunky and unreliable for different timezones, months with <> 30 days, and leap years.

Please reference this post below which goes into detail for how to get "last month":

[How to insert previous month of data into database Nifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887080/how-to-insert-previous-month-of-data-into-database-nifi/41887397#41887397)

Answer (score 0):

In the Case of NiFi you kind of have to play with the dates to get the outcome

if you have the dates you easily convert a date and then just hard set a day to get the 1st day of the month with a hard coded day

```
${now():toNumber():format('yyyy-MM-01')}
```

to get the last day of the month you can either use the script or play with the calc using epoch time.

so to get the last day of the previous month you can just use the date and convert the day into epoch time and subtract it from the epoch date to get last day of previous month

example

```
${now():toNumber():format('yyyy-MM-dd'):toDate('yyyy-MM-dd', 'GMT'):toNumber():minus(${now():toNumber():format('dd'):toNumber():multiply(86400):multiply(1000)}):format('yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

in this example above we convert the date to epoch format it to convert again, conversion happens to remove default timestamp and then we use the same formula to get just the day as a number to multiply it with 86400 seconds in a day and multiply that by 1000 for the epoch number to subtract from the date which is then formatted back into a date.

Raw Date: Thursday, August 26, 2021 11:20:31 AM

formatted: Thursday, August 26, 2021 12:00:00 AM

epoch of formatted date: 1629936000000

Subtract Epoch: 2246400000 (86400 seconds * 26 days * 1000)

result: 2021-07-31

alteratively you could first add a month and the work back to get the current day of the given month

this example is just to give you an idea of ways you can use built in date functions with epoch time to calculate the correct date, removing the issues with months that end on specific numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As I did not find any direct solution, my workaround has been to directly calculate the date wherever I need it, so I don't have to use nifi. In my case I wanted to calculate the first and last day of the last month so I could use it in a ExecuteSQL processor (Redshift).

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
WHERE date >= DATE_TRUNC('month', DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_DATE)) 
AND date <= LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_DATE));
```

---

```
DATE_TRUNC('month', DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_DATE)) => First day of the last month.

LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_DATE)) => Last day of the last month.
```

Similarly, you can check your usecase and calculate the date in the final process you need this date for. (notice that in SQL, if the column is of type DATE, we do not have to specify the format when doing the comparison).

Answer (score -1):

I try UpdateAttribute to minus month

```
test${now():toNumber():format('yyyyMM'):minus(1)}01
```